# SQL Sort in acesnding order, but with Nulls treated as max value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sorting, sql-order-by

With the below query I am selecting 2 fields, and sorting them in ascending order:

```
Select Customer, ForecastReady Order By ForecastReady
```

My data comes out like below:

```
Customer        ForecastReady
ASHD    
ASHD    
ASHD            20/12/2019
ASHD            14/01/2020
ASHD            14/01/2020
ASHD            14/01/2020
ASHD            14/01/2020
```

How can I get it so the Null values are last, and in ascending order

```
 Customer       ForecastReady
 ASHD           20/12/2019
 ASHD           14/01/2020
 ASHD           14/01/2020
 ASHD           14/01/2020
 ASHD           14/01/2020
 ASHD   
 ASHD
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use conditional logic :

```
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN ForecastReady IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), ForecastReady
```

Comment: thanks, I was attempting it all wrong, I was going to select my data where ForecastReady was not null, order it, then union the same data but where ForecastReady was null

Answer (score 3):

Like so:

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN ForecastReady IS NULL THEN 1 END, ForecastReady
```

The `CASE WHEN ForecastReady IS NULL THEN 1 END` part results in NULL or 1 which sort according to your requirement.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense now